# How to print not time-series using dygraphs

Tags: javascript, plot, dygraphs

I have the following dataset

```
   X     Y
------------
9.2294   40
9.65712  60
10.0633  80
10.1865  90
10.2844  100
10.4122  120
10.5217  140
10.5776  160
10.5995  180
10.6237  200
10.563   250
```

and I want to plot a Profile (Y is the elevation) connecting the point on the basis of the Y order and not to the X order (it is a XY graph and not a time-series)... with dygraphs it seems to be not possible.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advanced".

Answer (score 0):

dygraphs requires that your data be sorted by the first column (the x-axis). You might be able to pull of what you're asking for using a [custom plotter](http://blog.dygraphs.com/2012/08/introducing-custom-plotters.html), but it's not a natural fit. You'll have an easier time using either D3 or a library with built-in support for plots like this.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve this with the use of a custom plotter function based on the link @danvk posted.

It works, but it's not pretty. I would love to hear suggestions on how to

- avoid using a custom plotter
- finding the canvas x/y positions without linear regression
- reusing existing drawing code for better features support and avoiding code duplication

below is the code and a screenshot of the graphs it renders

```
plotter: function(e) {
// dygraph series
var seriesPoints = e.allSeriesPoints[e.seriesIndex];
// real series
var realData = table.lists.get(e.seriesIndex);
// build a linear regression to map from real values to canvas x/y based on a sample of 2 points
var pa, pb;
seriesPoints.forEach(p => { 
    if (!pa && p.xval != null && p.yval != null) pa = p;
    else if (pa && !pb && p.xval != null && p.yval != null) pb = p;
});
if (!pa || !pb) {
    return;
}
baseDataX = pa.xval;
baseDataXMul = (pb.canvasx - pa.canvasx) / (pb.xval - pa.xval);
baseDataY = pa.yval;
baseDataYMul = (pb.canvasy - pa.canvasy) / (pb.yval - pa.yval);
var getPoint = function(i) { return { canvasx: pa.canvasx + baseDataXMul * (realData[i].x - baseDataX),  canvasy: pa.canvasy + baseDataYMul * (realData[i].y - baseDataY) }; }
// draw the line, iterating on the data points of the REAL series, each of which os properly sorted
var ctx = e.drawingContext;
ctx.beginPath();
var p0 = getPoint(0);
if (p0) ctx.moveTo(p0.canvasx, p0.canvasy);
for (var i = 1; i < realData.length; i++) {
    var p = getPoint(i);
    if (p) ctx.lineTo(p.canvasx, p.canvasy);
}
ctx.stroke(); }
```

[image: multiple non-time-series graphs representing efficient frontiers]